# Ошибка объявления функции в svg - FireBug Mozilla

Tags: javascript

Использую вот такую конструкцию для динамической смены значений в SVG-файле:

```js
window.svgload_html = function(evt) {
  var svg = evt.target, //Вот он, корневой узел DOM SVG
      f = false, fig1 = svg.getElementById("fig1"), fig2 = svg.getElementById("fig2");
  setInterval(function() {
    f = !f;
    fig1.attributes["fill"].value = f ? "black" : "red";
    fig1.attributes["stroke"].value = f ? "red" : "black";
    fig2.attributes["fill"].value = f ? "red": "black";
    fig2.attributes["stroke"].value = f ? "black" : "red";
  }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" 
  viewBox="0 0 200 100" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
  onload="svgload_svg(evt);" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<defs>
<script type="application/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
function svgload_svg(evt) {

  var w = window, w0 = null;
  while (w && !w.svgload_html && w != w0) {
    w0 = w;
    w = w.parent;
  }
  if (w)

  // вот на эту строку ссылается Mozilla, считая её ошибочной
  w.svgload_html(evt);
}
]]></script>
</defs>

<rect id="fig1" x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" />
<circle id="fig2" cx="150" cy="50" r="40" fill="black" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
```

Всё прекрасно работает в двух браузерах - CHROME и OPERA, но MOZILLA снова отличился. Выкидывает ошибку: **TypeError: w.svgload_html is not a function** ссылаясь на эту строку: **w.svgload_html(evt);** и стопорит дальнейшее исполнение скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Друзья, как обойти эту проблему? Спасибо...

P.S. Попробовал объявить функцию выше, но ничего не вышло и вот почему. 
Решил в отладчиках браузеров сравнить вывод svg-файла, в котором и объявляется функция w.svgload_html(evt);
и оказалось, что Mozilla попросту не отображает, вырезает содержимое. Поэтому и ругается на функцию, потому что попросту её нет. Как тут побороть? Посоветуйте...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В FF прекрасно мигают ваши квадрат и круг. Без ошибок.

Comment: все прекрасно работает, посмотрите у себя где вы дикларируете функцию `svgload_html`

Comment: 1. Вы код выполняете во фрейме, нажав кнопку Выполнить код? Это я уже видел, что работает пример.Но думаю код там проходит компиляцию под движок WebKit... Этот движок автоматом исправляет некоторые некритичные расхождения в синтаксисе и т.д. А вот Мозилла конкретно указал на неопределённую функцию... Ну не считает он её функцией! 

2. Где я декларирую функцию - тоже всё верно, ведь работает в двух браузерах без проблем.

Так что друзья мои - это не ответ. Жду других ответов.

Comment: @МатвейУваров Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: я вроде конкретно всё разжевал и описал, ну если вам непонятно или не знаете ответ - проходите мимо. Не мешайте другим...

Comment: вот человек на toster.ru конкретно ответил на конкретно поставленный вопрос:
"Вызов функции происходит раньше чем браузер находит функцию. 
Либо смотрите порядок загрузки своей страницы, либо просто выше svgload_svg объявите свою svgload_html" И это верный ответ!..

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение самостоятельно - просто сгенерировал элемент:

```js
// Генерируем и вставляем элемент
var object = document.createElement('object');
document.getElementById('monitor_svg').appendChild(object);

object.setAttribute( 'type', 'image/svg+xml' );
object.setAttribute( 'width', '420' );
object.setAttribute( 'height', 'auto' );
object.setAttribute( 'data', '//.../file.svg' );

// Объявляем функцию
window.svgload_html = function(evt) {
  var svg = evt.target, //Вот он, корневой узел DOM SVG
      f = false, fig1 = svg.getElementById("fig1"), fig2 = svg.getElementById("fig2");
  setInterval(function() {
    f = !f;
    fig1.attributes["fill"].value = f ? "black" : "red";
    fig1.attributes["stroke"].value = f ? "red" : "black";
    fig2.attributes["fill"].value = f ? "red": "black";
    fig2.attributes["stroke"].value = f ? "black" : "red";
  }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<!-- вставляем элемент object в div -->
<div id="monitor_svg" class="uk-text-center"></div>
```